# Android app how to get photos of a specific user

Tags: php, android, image, picasso

I'm creating a social app similar to instagram on `Android studio`.

Users will be able to upload and view photos in this app.

The photos are saved on a Cloud in a folder called "ProfileImage" and the `URL` of the photos is saved on the `MySql` database, along with the `ID` of the photo and the user's `ID`.

To get the photos I would like to use [Picasso](https://square.github.io/picasso/).

If for example the user A wants to look at his photos, the app will have to show him only his photos, that is I will have to get the `URLs` of the photos that have the id of the user A.

Picasso to get the photos use the following code  `Picasso.get().load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").into(imageView);`

But the problem is that I don't know the specific `URL` of the photos.

One solution I thought of is to get the `URLs` of the photos via `PHP` and pass them into an android variable that I will use as a `URL` variable for [Picasso](https://square.github.io/picasso/).

But this solution seems slow to me, in the sense that the photo will not be displayed immediately, but seconds will have to pass.

Can anyone recommend a faster and perhaps better solution than mine?

Comment: If your images or Urls are saved on Server . Let your Server serve the image via a Rest API .. Because only it can know the images belongs to particular user on behalf of some Primary Key (User Id) .. And Picasso is just a Image Loading library it does not have to do anything with this its just load an image on a target that's it ..

Comment: So I should show the images by retrofit or volley or others?

Comment: Yeah!!! not the only way but if you are going to use a Rest API you can use any one of these libraries..

Comment: Do you think there is a better way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, Upload your image to server and save image url inside mysql database not image itself. Create one api that returns user info including image url.